# python 3.9 Package Relative Imports not working

Tags: python, relative-import

I am setting up a sample python package using the "Package Relative Imports" syntax, referring to [this document](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports). And it is not working, the Relative Imports in b.py ran into problems. Here are my file structure (all __init.py__ are empty)

```
lib/
    dir1/
        __init.py__
        a.py
    dir2/
        __init.py__
        b.py
    __init.py__
    c.py
```

File a.py

```
def a_foo(a, b):
    return a + b
```

File b.py

```
from ..dir1.a import a_foo
def b_bar():
    return a_foo(1,2)
```

File c.py

```
from dir2.b import b_bar
print(b_bar())
```

I ran c.py and got the following error

```
PS D:\tmp\py> python c.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\tmp\py\c.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dir2.b import b_bar
  File "D:\tmp\py\dir2\b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..dir1.a import a_foo
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I think I structured everything according to the document. Not sure why the relative import is not working. I have a Python 3.9.7 running in Windows 10.

Comment: Please do not change the question with follow-up question once you have an answer. If you have another question, follow the procedure for new questions: first search (your question about using `__main__` has been asked and answered many times before), and if you couldn't find the answer, ask a new question here. Hint: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `from dir2.b` is being interpreted as an absolute import, not relative. The docs you refer to say:

Try:

```py
from .dir2.b import b_bar
```

Note the preceding period. It means look in the current directory for "dir2"

Then call it using

```
python -c "import lib.c"
```

Comment: Yes, I was just about to write the same. And calling `python c.py` is wrong as well, but `python -c "import lib.c"` from the parent directory will give the expected result after your suggested modification.

Comment: Personally I've just gone all the way and configure with a pyproject.toml/setup.cfg and setup.py. All scripts calling the library have absolute imports while anything within in library is relative. This has never failed me and ensures portability.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I am new to Python. I think I need to more study how the file structure works when building a project with many folders and files. I made my code work for now using your comments. But do not quite understand how it all works.

Comment: @QiaoLi, I have quite some experience with Python, but I think the importing system is one of the most complex things in Python and it has often confused me as well. It's not the easiest thing to start with. But I'm glad you got it working :-)

Answer (score -1):

To get a simple idea Lets look at the directory tree again

```
lib
├── c.py
├── dir1
│   ├── a.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── dir2
│   ├── b.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

**Important things**

1. In this tree, the top most `__init__.py` file is in the root directory.
2. All other subfolders with python scripts are included `__init__.py`

OK, Here comes the point. When you are trying to do relative import with `..` it tries to import from `lib.dir1.a`, But there is no `__init__.py` at the same level with `lib` folder. That's why you get `ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` error. Because of python package importer doesn't identify `lib` folder as the top level package.

When you are trying to relative import with `.` , you checks `dir2.dir1.a` , which doesn't exit. Sow it will give you `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir2.dir1'` error

OK lets check whether it's true or not. lets add new folder `dir3` within dir1 and `d.py`,`e.py` and `__init__.py` inside it

Here is the **NEW** directory tree

```
lib
├── c.py
├── dir1
│   ├── a.py
│   ├── dir3
│   │   ├── d.py
│   │   ├── e.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── dir2
│   ├── b.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

And here are the **NEW** file contents

**a.py**

```
def a_foo(a, b):
    return a + b
```

**b.py**

```
from dir1.a import a_foo
def b_bar():
    return a_foo(1,2)
```

**e.py**

```
def e_foo(a, b):
    return a + b
```

**d.py**

```
from ..a import a_foo
from .e import e_foo
def d_bar():
    return a_foo(1,2) 

def d_foo():
    return e_foo(1,2)
```

`..` , Which tries to import from `dir1.a`, which exists and also which is accessible.

`.` , Which tries to import from `dir3.e`, which exists and also which is accessible.

**c.py**

```
from dir2.b import b_bar
from dir1.dir3.d import d_bar,d_foo
print("b_bar:", b_bar())
print("d_bar:", d_bar())
print("d_foo:", d_foo())
```

Now lets run `c.py`. The result is

```
b_bar: 3
d_bar: 3
d_foo: 3
```

Which indicates our relative import has been successful inside `d.py`.

OK then. I think this will solve your problem. We can use relative import in files which are in depth from the root-package. But when they are too close (within one or two levels), it's impossible.

Actually we can use `.` to import from python scripts in same level but not when the script is in the top most directory.